# Two random sequences converging to one another

Tags: terminology, convergence

Consider two infinite sequences $X_1, X_2, \dots$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$.

Suppose that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |F_{X_n}(z) - F_{Y_n}(z)| = 0 ~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

for all $z$ at which both cdf's are continuous.

I believe in that case you can*not* say that $X_n {\rightarrow}^d~ Y_n$, since convergence in distribution is, strictly speaking, only defined when $X_n$ converges some "fixed" random variable $X$. Is that correct?

If that's the case, how can you talk about this relationship between $X_n$ and $Y_n$?

I am thinking, for example, of $\bar{X}_n$ from random samples of increasing size. I'd like to use the correct terminology to say that the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ gets closer and closer to $N(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$ as $n$ increases, in the sense of (1). I don't want to say that $\bar{X}_n$ converges in distribution to $N(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$, because that seems like I am twisting the definition. Is there any other commonly accepted terminology I can use instead?

Comment: "$X_n {\rightarrow}^d~ Y_n$" plainly makes no sense, because "$n$" is undefined in the limit.  You are therefore asking how one talks about something meaningless!  To solve your actual problem, simply study $\sqrt n \bar X_n,$ whose distribution converges to a Normal$(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution.

Comment: @whuber How about the property defined by (1)? Is that also unwell-defined or meaningless? Is there not a way to talk about that property?

Comment: (1) makes sense.  The problem is that it only says the distribution functions of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ grow closer to each other--but there's no guarantee either approaches any kind of limit.  For instance, take random variables $U,V$ with different distributions. For even $n$ set $X_n=Y_n=U$ and for odd $n$ set $X_n=Y_n=V.$ Then trivially (1) holds because for all $n$ and $z,$ $|F_{X_n}(z) - F_{Y_n}(z)| = 0$ implying its limit is zero, but it is obvious neither of the sequences $(X_n)$ or $(Y_n)$ has a limit. You might say their distributions are "asymptotically equal," FWIW.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for your second comment. If you turned it into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it so the question is marked as answered.